# Why can't we embed an executable in a question?

Tags: discussion

I browsed SO, and [I found a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31192491/system-function-causes-screen-to-clear) with a problem which seems to be tied to the OP and which can't be replicated.

Then I asked him to attach the executable to his post, but I was told that it doesn't fit SO format.

In this case,

- It would allow us to disassemble the generated code,
- It would be way more handy than browsing thousands of lines of ASM,
- It would be perfectly safe, if OP adds a virustotal analysis.

Then why an executable couldn't be added to a question?

Comment: NO, no and no.  NO executables!

Comment: Yep, lets let people attach viruses to questions. Great idea!

Comment: "Perfectly safe" would only apply if VirusTotal was completely infallible and could detect every possible Trojan or exploit someone could put in executable code. I've never seen an antivirus service that could claim that.

Comment: I would be happy to agree with @LoveMetal proposal if he/she imdeminifies all SO users against infection, (with no financial limit).  Well, OP?  How rich are you, and how big is your mansion and grounds?

Comment: @MartinJames PLEASE LET'S DO SO, I have some ..... code.... I wanna upload to Stack :D

Comment: On a more serious note @LoveMetal, there is no way to be 100% certain, even if it`s not a virus, that it's a safe executable for your computer. And Stack will get into a LOT of problems if it starts doing that and it messes up people's computers, or opens backdoor vulnerabilities, etc etc

Comment: VT do a filechecking with more than 40 solutions. If it doesn't detect anything, then another antivirus hardly could. You would need to have a very good level to bypass this analysis, and in this case I don't think that you would post your deadly weapon on a niche Q&A site. And even then, if the purpose of this executable is to be disassembled, you would execute it in a sandbox.

Comment: How would we know that the AV report provided was a result of scanning the executable provided?

Comment: @LoveMetal so you admit yourself that it COULD happen. How would stack deal with that? I can only imagine the meta question "HELP, I DOWNLOADED AN EXE FROM A QUESTION AND MY PC FRIED"

Comment: @Martin James It's up to you to read correctly an URL.

Comment: @Patrice - on the other hand, it may burn a couple of rep junkies who feel the need to answer *everything*... hrm... the enemy of my enemy...

Comment: Sure, URL's are never misread, or misleading, or point anywhere they do not purport to do.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables hmmmm.... see, this is actually a good pro for this Feature :P

Comment: Leat's face it, this dead horse does not even need a light whipping, never mind a flogging.  If anything, this question reads like an ad for VirusTotal.

Comment: MOAR_FLOGGING.EXE

Comment: @LoveMetal SO employee? Who is an SO employee here?

Comment: 'Created by: Hispasec', 'Owner: Google Inc', 'Holding Co: NSA'

Comment: @LoveMetal Uh... The only employee that's said anything here was Oded. And he said one thing and left. So... What's your "SO employee" comment supposed to mean?

Comment: Misread usernames sorry

Comment: @Kendra Oded is not an employee.... the diamond doesn`t come with a paycheck, no?

Comment: @Patrice Check his profile. Oded _is_ an employee.

Comment: @Kendra he's both!?! Cheeky Bas..... Fair enough :P I just looked at the diamond and assumed that's what was referenced. My bad

Comment: Lets call a spade a spade.

Comment: I haven't the heart to go on with this thread..

Comment: ..so I'm going out clubbing.

Comment: Thats **all** we need - users uploading an exe with the helpful title *It Dont Work - Thanks Advanced - URGENT*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No.

---

Running code, even "verified safe" code from the internet is a **horrible** idea. Code can be completely virus free and still be malicious. Even worse, it can be [unintentionally](https://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee-Old-and-abbandoned/issues/123) malicious.

```
rm -rf /usr /lib/nvidia-current/xorg/xorg
```

Whoops, an extra space is in your shell command that your program executes. Well, goodbye `/usr`

---

If you need a disassembly, a snippet should be placed in the question. If the disassembly is to long, it isn't a great question to begin with. We require short snippets of source code - not hundreds or thousands of lines of code - this is the same.